# how to loop over all my List items and extract the value from each key?

Tags: python, jinja2

this is what i am trying to do :

```
{% set count = 0 %}
{% for k,v in results_list[count].items() %}
   <td>{{ v }}</td>
{% set count = count + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```

instead of doing it manually
 like this :

```
{% for k,v in results_list[0].items() %}
<td>{{ v }} </td>
{% endfor %}
{% for k,v in results_list[1].items() %}
<td>{{ v }} </td>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of how `results_list` looks lie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you need a nested loop.

**Ex:**

```
{% for i in results_list %}
    {% for k,v in i.items() %}
        <td>{{ v }} </td>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: thanks . it worked :D
sometimes the answer is really simple but we make it really complicate